# Did I use enough seed?

Tags: lawn, watering, grass

8 days ago today, I brought in two dump truck loads of dirt because my lawn was in horrible shape when I moved here. It had about 4-5 inches that needed to be back filled. It was good soil too, rich And black. I planted Bermuda seed from my local seed company. They said 4-8 pounds covers 1000 square foot. I got 27 pounds. The area is around 3700 square foot. I’ve water it lightly and frequently every day since but on the second day, I didn’t realize how fast the soil dries out so it dried out pretty bad.

I woke up to water this morning and saw patches are coming in but it’s not coming in everywhere and it’s not thick.

[image]

Did I use enough seed or did it die off from the second day when it dried out? Any recommendations?

Edit: the picture is a spot where it’s coming in the thickest. A bunch of bare spots in many places

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is the first day when you've seen any grass sprouts. My advice for now is to have a bit of patience. Not all the seeds will germinate and grow at exactly the same rate. You'll probably see more growth over the next few days. It's possible that you delayed some of the seeds by letting it dry out on the second day, but it probably (hopefully) didn't actually kill those seeds.

Give it a week. If you still have very thin, patchy growth with some completely bare spots, plant more seed to the areas that are bare or have only thin grass coverage. But do keep in mind that the grass will fill in as it grows. The densest area in your photograph looks like reasonable coverage for early growth.

Now that the grass is growing, it's absolutely essential that you don't forget to water. The sprouts don't have enough of a root system to tolerate any drought yet. Check on the soil in the middle of the day to make sure it's not drying out then, especially on hot sunny days.

Comment: Gotcha. I’ve actually noticed now there’s a small purple colored grass germinating along with the thin bright green grass germinating like the picture above. Is that two different types of Bermuda or something?

Comment: Seedlings are quite tricky to ID, but if you post that as a separate question with a photo of both types of seedling, someone may be able to answer.